# Error when start mongoDB with --storageEngine options: "unrecognised option"

Tags: mongodb, rocksdb, database

I tried to start mongod service with "--storageEngine=rocksdb" but I got error of ""unrecognised option" .
I tried to see all the option variables by running help command and didn't see "--storageEngine" option for mongod.
Below are all the option variable i could see for mongod.

```
root@ubuntu:~/MongoDb/mongo# mongod --help
Allowed options:

General options:
-h [ --help ]               show this usage information
 --version                   show version information
 -f [ --config ] arg         configuration file specifying additional    options
 -v [ --verbose ]            be more verbose (include multiple times for more 
                          verbosity e.g. -vvvvv)
--quiet                     quieter output
--port arg                  specify port number - 27017 by default
--bind_ip arg               comma separated list of ip addresses to     listen on
                          - all local ips by default
--maxConns arg              max number of simultaneous connections - 20000 by
                          default
--logpath arg               log file to send write to instead of stdout - has
                          to be a file, not directory
--logappend                 append to logpath instead of over-writing
--pidfilepath arg           full path to pidfile (if not set, no pidfile is 
                          created)
--keyFile arg               private key for cluster authentication
--setParameter arg          Set a configurable parameter
--nounixsocket              disable listening on unix sockets
--unixSocketPrefix arg      alternative directory for UNIX domain sockets 
                          (defaults to /tmp)
--fork                      fork server process
--syslog                    log to system's syslog facility instead of file 
                          or stdout
--auth                      run with security
--cpu                       periodically show cpu and iowait utilization
--dbpath arg                directory for datafiles - defaults to /data/db/
--diaglog arg               0=off 1=W 2=R 3=both 7=W+some reads
--directoryperdb            each database will be stored in a separate 
                          directory
--ipv6                      enable IPv6 support (disabled by default)
--journal                   enable journaling
--journalCommitInterval arg how often to group/batch commit (ms)
--journalOptions arg        journal diagnostic options
--jsonp                     allow JSONP access via http (has security 
                          implications)
--noauth                    run without security
--nohttpinterface           disable http interface
--nojournal                 disable journaling (journaling is on by default 
                          for 64 bit)
--noprealloc                disable data file preallocation - will often hurt
                          performance
--noscripting               disable scripting engine
--notablescan               do not allow table scans
--nssize arg (=16)          .ns file size (in MB) for new databases
--profile arg               0=off 1=slow, 2=all
--quota                     limits each database to a certain number of files
                          (8 default)
--quotaFiles arg            number of files allowed per db, requires --quota
--repair                    run repair on all dbs
--repairpath arg            root directory for repair files - defaults to 
                          dbpath
--rest                      turn on simple rest api
--shutdown                  kill a running server (for init scripts)
--slowms arg (=100)         value of slow for profile and console log
--smallfiles                use a smaller default file size
--syncdelay arg (=60)       seconds between disk syncs (0=never, but not 
                          recommended)
--sysinfo                   print some diagnostic system information
--upgrade                   upgrade db if needed

Replication options:
--oplogSize arg       size to use (in MB) for replication op log. default is 
                    5% of disk space (i.e. large is good)

Master/slave options (old; use replica sets instead):
--master              master mode
--slave               slave mode
--source arg          when slave: specify master as <server:port>
--only arg            when slave: specify a single database to     replicate
--slavedelay arg      specify delay (in seconds) to be used when applying 
                    master ops to slave
--autoresync          automatically resync if slave data is stale

Replica set options:
--replSet arg           arg is <setname>[/<optionalseedhostlist>]
--replIndexPrefetch arg specify index prefetching behavior (if secondary) 
                      [none|_id_only|all]

Sharding options:
--configsvr           declare this is a config db of a cluster; default port 
                    27019; default dir /data/configdb
--shardsvr            declare this is a shard db of a cluster; default port 
                    27018

SSL options:
--sslOnNormalPorts              use ssl on configured ports
--sslPEMKeyFile arg             PEM file for ssl
--sslPEMKeyPassword arg         PEM file password
--sslCAFile arg                 Certificate Authority file for SSL
--sslCRLFile arg                Certificate Revocation List file for    SSL
--sslWeakCertificateValidation  allow client to connect without presenting a 
                              certificate
--sslFIPSMode                   activate FIPS 140-2 mode at startup
```

Please let me know about how to use the "--storageEngine" option variable .

Comment: Well, then `storageEngine` is not a correct param for the mongo version you are running...

Comment: Which version of mongo are you running?

Comment: I doubt it will be a reasonably good idea to run an exotic (aka not especially well understood or documented) storage engine as a beginner with MongoDB. You should get started with WT, which for the majority of use cases is more than sufficient. Performance problems tend to be a problem with data modeling and proper indexing rather than with the storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all, check your mongodb version. Mongdb supports this option since 3.2.**
**Besides, official version of mongodb not support rocksdb yet.**
Perhaps [mongo-rocks](https://github.com/mongodb-partners/mongo-rocks) is what you want.

Comment: I have installed mongo-rocks only .The problem is mongoDB as well as mongo-rocks does not have option of "--storageEngine" .Please check the output of "mongod --help" attached with the question .

Answer (score 0):

Upto now MongoDB support WiredTiger and MMAPv1. refer below link

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage-engines/

If you want to use RockDB Storage engine, you need to install RockDB libs, To install or Integrate with MongoDB follow below link

https://github.com/mongodb-partners/mongo-rocks

Comment: I followed the same link .I have installed mongo-rocks only .

Answer (score 0):

It was mongoDB version issue .